# tmux session must exit correctly on clicking close button

Tags: configuration, tmux

How can a tmux session exit correctly i.e. completely on the quit/exit by way of clicking terminal window's close button, as it'll keep the tmux session remains on its OS pid

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly"? I think you're missing the entire point of tmux.

Comment: It's not a bug; it's a feature. `tmux` is meant to be used where connectivity is spotty so your session persists in the face of adversity. In other words, it's not *supposed* to exit under these circumstances, as @ArturMeinild pointed out in his answer. What are your goals in using `tmux`, or what problem are you trying to solve that prompted you to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of `tmux`'s design goals is that the session persists when you close the terminal.

So by default, if you want to close a `tmux` session, you must actively do so with the command:

```
tmux kill-session -t <session-name>
```

If you somehow wish to disable the default behavior, you can set the `destroy-unattached` option in your `~/.tmux.conf` file, like this:

```
set-option -g destroy-unattached on
```

With this option set, `tmux` will automatically close any sessions not attached to a client.